# How do I get the current path in my imported js file in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have 2 files `A.js` and `B.js`, they are structured as follows:

```
packgages
|
 – B
   |
    - B.js
A.js
```

In my `A.js` I simply do this:

```
import B.js
```

In my `B.js` I want to know the full path to this file (`B.js`):

```
console.log(__dirname);
```

So if I execute `cd packages/B; node B.js` I get the following result:

```
/Users/luke/Projekte/writejs/code/verne/packages/B
```

But if I excecute `node A.js` I get this:

```
/Users/luke/Projekte/writejs/code/verne
```

See that the `__dirname` does not refer to the file from which is it called but to the file that executes it in its root.

Is there a way to get the full path to `/packages/B` no matter which file I am importing it from?

Comment: That's a really strange behaviour, Node docs says exactly the opposite [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_scope).

Comment: Interesting. That is really weird. Think I need to do some investigation.

Comment: Also, I have just tried it in my environment (Node v9.2.1 on Windows) with two simple modules and one includes the others, and it works exactly as the doc reports.

Comment: Well in my case I am doing this as part of a rollup ( https://rollupjs.org/ ) config, where i am importing another config file, maybe rollup does something it should not do

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with Rollup, but from what I can understand from the introduction on its page, its purpose is to transpile ES6 scripts into a single js file. So if have the following files:

**moduleA.js**

```
import p from "./myModules/moduleB";

console.log(__dirname);
console.log(__filename);

p();
```

**myModules/moduleB.js**

```
export default function () {
  console.log(__dirname);
  console.log(__filename);
}
```

When executing Rollup on moduleA.js

```
rollup -i moduleA.js -f cjs -o rollup.js
```

I obtain the following file:

**rollup.js**

```
'use strict';

function p () {
  console.log(__dirname);
  console.log(__filename);
}

console.log(__dirname);
console.log(__filename);

p();
```

As you can see, any reference to the previous structure is gone. Also, everything is in one single file, so the directory would not change.

I have also tried to find a way to maintain the directory structure when creating Rollup bundle, but can't find any solution.